# Scala pattern matching an equation case

Tags: scala, functional-programming, jvm, switch-statement

I want to pattern match if `x` is divisible by `y`, return true but I seem to have the syntax wrong and it keeps crashing.

```
def isDivisible (x: Int, y: Int) :Boolean = Int match {
    case (x % y == 0) => true
    case _ => false
}

isDivisible(10, 5)
```

What is the correct way of putting an equation as a case

Comment: How does it keep crashing? Does it even compile?

Comment: *I guess compile is a better term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on one of the comments, and in order to directly address your question, you would need to pattern match as follows:

```scala
def isDivisible(x: Int, y: Int): Boolean = (x, y) match {
  case (a, b) if a % b == 0 => true
  case _ => false
}

isDivisible(10, 5)
```

You need to pattern match on a single value, so we firstly need to wrap `x` and `y` into a *tuple*: `(x, y)`.

The first `case` statement then needs to extract the values from that *tuple* and has an `if` clause to determine if the first value (`a`, which is mapped to the value of `x`) is divisible by the second value (`b`, which is mapped to the value of `y`).

If the `if` clause succeeds, then the function will return `true`; otherwise, it will return `false`.

Clearly, it's inefficient in terms of both coding and execution resources to use pattern matching in this particular case. This is since the wrapping of the arguments into a tuple, then pattern matching for a tuple and breaking it apart again, is completely redundant. We can replace this directly with an `if` statement:

```scala
def isDivisible(x: Int, y: Int): Boolean = if(x % y == 0) true else false

isDivisible(10, 5)
```

However, since the value of the condition in the `if` statement maps to the same result, that too is redundant, and we can replace the `if` with the condition:

```scala
def isDivisible(x: Int, y: Int): Boolean = x % y == 0

isDivisible(10, 5)
```

Alternatively, you could pattern match on the result of the modulus calculation:

```scala
def isDivisible(x: Int, y: Int): Boolean = x % y match {
  case 0 => true
  case _ => false
}

isDivisible(10, 5)
```

Note, however, that the all of the above versions of this function will fail with an `ArithmeticException` if `y` is 0. You could handle that case using pattern matching:

```scala
def isDivisible(x: Int, y: Int): Boolean = y match {
  case 0 => false // Treat division by zero as indivisible.
  case _ => x % y == 0
}

isDivisible(10, 0)
```

Comment: That is very well explained. Thank you.
I did this below and it worked, but that was before I got your response.
`def isDivisible (x: Int, y: Int) :Boolean = Int match {
  case a if (x % y == 0) => true
  case _ => false
}`

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit of an overkill to use pattern matching in such a trivial example, simply define:

```
def isDivisible(x: Int, y: Int): Boolean = x % y == 0
```

Comment: Understood; But what is the correct way/ syntax to put an "equation" in scala pattern matching

Comment: @pokumars you can't not put an equation in a pattern match.

Comment: if you really wanted to pattern match `(x,y) match { case (a,b) if a % b == 0 => `. But that's just silly. And notice the renamed variables to avoid shadowing the "extracted" values from the method parameters. Silly.